# Custom UICollectionViewLayout With Equal Inter-Item Spacing

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview, uicollectionviewdelegate

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to designing what feels like it should be a fairly straightforward layout for my collection view. The heights of each cell are equal. The widths vary. The inter-item spacing should **always** be equal. The distance between rows should also always be equal. As more items are added, the width of the collection view will increase "intelligently." Let me give an example.

[image: Desired layout]

When I insert a new item, I will calculate the movement of items from rows (maybe the first item of row 1 moves up to row 0, maybe the first item of row 2 moves up to row 1. I then move it and the collection view grows wider.

[image: Colors added for illustrative purposes]

I feel like this should be reasonably straightforward but I'm struggling. 
Does anyone have some sample code that could help?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this using UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/